# PostGIS mismatch between 2D Distance ("<->" operator; geometry) and ST_Distance (geography) sorting orders

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

Using PostgreSQL 9.5.2, PostGIS 2.2, given the following geo coordinates:

```
'SRID=4326;POINT(24.8713597 60.1600568)'   -- Origin
'SRID=4326;POINT(24.87717970 60.19824480)' -- Destination A
'SRID=4326;POINT(24.91281220 60.15821350)' -- Destination B
'SRID=4326;POINT(24.91404950 60.16373390)' -- Destination C
'SRID=4326;POINT(24.91552820 60.16129280)' -- Destination D
```

Sorting by "geographical" distance ([ST_Distance method](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/geometry_distance_knn.html)):

```
select name, st_distance('SRID=4326;POINT(24.8713597 60.1600568)'::geography, geo)
from (select 'SRID=4326;POINT(24.87717970 60.19824480)'::geography as geo, 'A' as name
      union select 'SRID=4326;POINT(24.91281220 60.15821350)'::geography as geo, 'B' as name
      union select 'SRID=4326;POINT(24.91404950 60.16373390)'::geography as geo, 'C' as name
      union select 'SRID=4326;POINT(24.91552820 60.16129280)'::geography as geo, 'D' as name) tmp
order by 2;
```

Results in:

```
B,2311.075069284
C,2405.58508757
D,2456.504535795
A,4266.971129052
```

Whereas sorting by "geometrical" 2D distance ([<-> Operator](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/geometry_distance_knn.html)):

```
select name, 'SRID=4326;POINT(24.8713597 60.1600568)'::geometry <-> geom
from (select 'SRID=4326;POINT(24.87717970 60.19824480)'::geometry as geom, 'A' as name
      union select 'SRID=4326;POINT(24.91281220 60.15821350)'::geometry as geom, 'B' as name
      union select 'SRID=4326;POINT(24.91404950 60.16373390)'::geometry as geom, 'C' as name
      union select 'SRID=4326;POINT(24.91552820 60.16129280)'::geometry as geom, 'D' as name) tmp
order by 2;
```

Results in:

```
A,0.03862894955858695
B,0.041493463474867306
C,0.042847871457636175
D,0.04418579056948194
```

... And I would expect the order to be exactly the same.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is expected, since the earth is not flat and you are comparing Cartesian distances to geodesic lengths on an ellipsoid of revolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the calculations at 60 degrees of latitude. Here a degree of latitude is much larger than a degree of longitude. Specifically, at 60 degrees of latitude a degree of latitude is 111.412km, while a degree of longitude is 55.800km. This means that the separation in longitude value is much more important than the separation in latitude.

```
A 24.87717970 - 24.8713597 = 0.006...
B 24.91281220 - ... = 0.041...
C 24.91404950 - ... = 0.043...
D 24.91552820 - ... = 0.044
```

Which nicely corresponds to your result.